# How to let my code access assembly while impersonating

Tags: asp.net-core, filestream, assemblies, impersonation

I'm trying to read images on a shared folder using `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated`. The problem is that during impersonation, my code can't access the `System.Drawing.Common` assembly, probably because the impersonated user has no access on it, what can I do.

```
WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(safeAccessTokenHandle,() => {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);

            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string[] f = file.Split('.');
                    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fstream);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                    model.Archive.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage));
                    fstream.Close();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the error I get :

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Access is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me case anyone faced this problem
Add this line of code before WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated

```
Assembly.Load("System.Drawing.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");
```

Comment: This worked for me. Only I had to load 6 assemblies to get my impersonation to run correctly. I was using a try/catch to end up finding all the ones that I needed.